# How to get responsive sticky header which the header is using table?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150){  
        $('#header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('#header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

```css
#header
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 108px;
        height: 108px;
        background: #335C7D;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        
        // set animation
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        display:none;
    }

    #header.sticky 
    {
        position: fixed;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        height: 48px; 
        background: #827f7b;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 99999;
        display: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">

  <tr id="example" class="disappear">
    <td width="200px" id="text" style="font-weight: bold">content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label>Never</br><input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled /></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label>Rarely</br><input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled checked="checked"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label>Occasionally</br><input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label>Often</br><input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label>Constantly</br><input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label>Negligible</br><input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label>Mild</br><input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label>Moderate</br><input type="radio" name="ExpI" checked="checked" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label>Severe</br><input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label>Extremely severe</br><input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled></label></td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr id="header">
    <td width="230px"></td>
    <td width="40px">Never</td>
    <td width="40px">Rarely</td>
    <td width="40px">Occasionally</td>
    <td width="40px">Often</td>
    <td width="30px">Constantly</td>
    <td width="50px">Negligible</td>
    <td width="50px">Mild</td>
    <td width="50px">Moderate</td>
    <td width="50px">Severe</td>
    <td width="140px">Extremely severe</td>
    <td width="20px"></td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="empty">
    <td width="200px" id="text"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="30px">F</td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">I</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

I am planing to get appear a sticky header when user scroll over the entire row of rating guide(easy for user to see the rating guide instead of all empty radio box, it would be messy for user.) So I write a table row which is name #header and it was hidden at first, and will be appear when break height value (150px).

My problem is:

1) How to I make sure all the alignment are correct when I resize my browser? Because the alignment of rating guide will incorrect if I resize browser.

2) How to addclass to my #header row using method of check if user had slide over #header row instead of set break height value (150px) directly, this is because if I resize browser, it will appear earlier and not the correct position.

Here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/k77vhf14/

Thanks.

Comment: This is an example for what I want, but it is using something that I don't understand, so I not plan to use it. [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a code for your requirements

the problem is that when the `#header` has `position:fixed` , the widths the td have , are taken in consideration whereas the `td` widths from `#example` , they are not taken in consideration

for the future you should know that `td { width:number px }` doesn't work, you need to use `min-width:`

anyway, so i added the widths from `#example td` to the corresponding `#header td` using a `for loop`

also added a dynamic condition on scroll depending on the `#header` row height

hope this is good for you

see snippet or > [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k77vhf14/1/)

```js
var headHeight = $("#header").height(),
  tdlength = $("#example td").length
for (i = 0; i < tdlength; i++) {
  var tdWidth = $("#example td:eq(" + i + ")").width()
  $("#header td:eq(" + i + ")").css({
    "min-width": tdWidth,
    "width": tdWidth
  })
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > headHeight) {
    $('#header').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('#header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  // set animation
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
label {
  font-size: 15px;
}
td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#header td:first-child {
  visibility: hidden
}
#header.sticky td:not(:first-child) {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header.sticky {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #827f7b;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mata">

</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">

  <tr id="example" class="disappear">
    <td width="200px" id="text" style="font-weight: bold">content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>Never</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>Rarely</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled checked="checked">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>Occasionally</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>Often</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>Constantly</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpF" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>Negligible</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>Mild</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>Moderate</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpI" checked="checked" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>Severe</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>Extremely severe</br>
        <input type="radio" name="ExpI" disabled>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr id="header">
    <td width="">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">Never</td>
    <td width="40px">Rarely</td>
    <td width="40px">Occasionally</td>
    <td width="40px">Often</td>
    <td width="30px">Constantly</td>
    <td width="50px">Negligible</td>
    <td width="50px">Mild</td>
    <td width="50px">Moderate</td>
    <td width="50px">Severe</td>
    <td width="40px">Extremely severe</td>
    <td width="20px"></td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="empty">
    <td width="200px" id="text"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="40px"></td>
    <td width="30px"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"></td>
    <td width="30px">F</td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">I</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">Content</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="text" class="numFr" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="text" class="numIr" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  






</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want :D